# read vector from txt file in python

Tags: python, vector, archive

I need read from txt file the next vector:

```
 [177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L]
```

I need put in variable x this vector, 
I need when I put

```
print x [2]
```

python only show me `232`

Im trying with

```
f = open ('achive.txt', 'r')
x=[line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
```

suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact content (give some example lines) of the file? Does it have just 1 line with this vector or many lines with a vector in each line? If it is many lines then what do you want to do with them?

Comment: What error message did you receive?  Could the filename be misspelled in the `open` statement? Also, you need to explicitly convert strings to numbers.

Comment: is a program that encrypts a text file, and save it in a txt ,  and another program reads and decodes , using public and private keys, send me the error is

Traceback ( most recent call last ) :
  File " descifrador.py " , line 36, in < module>
    print ciphertext [2]
IndexError : list index out of range

I have tried several ways to read the file

Comment: i need python read this log numbers from the txt file.

Comment: Please post a self contained example. A short mockup file that mimics the structure of your actual file, your code, a short description of what you want your code to do,  a short description of the error/problem you are having and how you have tried to solve it.

Comment: And please [edit] your question and put all that information in the post itself, **not** in comments.

Comment: This seems to be really common as the same recurrent question keeps coming on SO almost every other day. Which program writes such files???? I hate to see file content evaluation just because some crappy program writes files in a crappy format.

Comment: have you come any further?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a bit hard to answer without knowing what you are trying to do, let me just point you to `ast.literal_eval` for now. `ast.literal_eval` is the safe version of `eval` that can evaluate literal Python strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dictionaries, `True`, `False` and `None`.

Here's a demo how you would use it.

Demo file input.txt:

```
[177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L]
[178L, 194L, 233L, 185L, 201L]
```

Reading the lines as lists, print every list and its third element:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open('input.txt') as inp:
...     for line in inp:
...         vec = literal_eval(line)
...         print vec, vec[2]
... 
[177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L] 232
[178L, 194L, 233L, 185L, 201L] 233
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like list of long integers.
So if you really trust the origin of this file you could use something like:

```
>>> x = eval('[177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L]')
>>> x
[177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L]
>>> x[0]
177L
>>> x
[177L, 193L, 232L, 184L, 200L]
>>> x[2]
232L
```

Could be something like that:

```
vectors = []
with open('archive.txt', 'r') as arch:
    for line in arch:
        vectors.append(eval(line.rstrip()))
```

Comment: *"So if you really trust to source of this file (...)"* ...and if not?

Comment: @jDo then you use `ast.literal_eval` as in my suggestion :)

Comment: @timgeb Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

isinstance evalue if x is a list and return True or False,

eval() makes something alike 'linestr' to real value

```
myfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
data = myfile.readlines()
for x in data:
    if isinstance(eval(x), list):
         vector=eval(x) # you must use append if need add more list
print vector[2]
232

#if you use append, must ['line number']['value number']
#if you have multiples arrays in lines, Example:
data = myfile.readlines()
vector = []
for x in data:
    if isinstance(eval(x),list):
         vector.append(eval(x))
print vector[0][2]
232
print vector[1][3]
4442
```